# MongoDB instance partitioned by date

Tags: mongodb

I would like to have two mongo instances: the first one would store data from, let's assume, last 7 days and the other instance would contain all remaining data.

Also, I have application which retrieves data from database. I expect full transparency ie. when I ask for data from 3 days it talks to first instance, but when I ask for 3 month old data it uses both instances to build query results.

What technique should I employ to achieve this goal? I read about sharding, but did not found info about sharding by date dynamically. I mean I can partition by date, but key is constant, so I will have more and more data on first instance.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to split your data across two MongoDB instances in this particular way? Are you concerned about data size, or read performance, or write performance, or load handling, etc ?

Comment: In any case, I think this is not really about programming, so it is outside the scope of stackoverflow. I'm going to recommend it be migrated to [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @VinceBowdren I am concerned about database size. Currently we have one mongo instance on SSD disc, but its space is starting to run out. We'd like to move oldest data to big HDD, so that we have still fast access to newest records.

Comment: If that is your concern, then [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) is what to do about it. If you try to split the data yourself, then you will run into problems with what happens when the data is being migrated (overnight?) for example. Sharding is designed to take care of that for you, and will scale as far as you need, across as many servers as you need.